# Saving Sessions In Database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

In LAMP environment I heard many times that it is best to save your sessions to a database security-wise(Saw it in a Codeigniter tutorial) . 
Any thoughts on why this is true ? What is the difference between the server application saving it into a file(which is what php does by default if I'm not wrong) or to a db ? 
I know that involving a db might add another layer of protection since it's password protected , is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

If someone is able to watch session files on your server than the security is already broken in a fatal way. It would be easy for an attacker to grab the database passwords as well.

I see the most advantage of saving sessions to a database in the fact, that is good for scalability of your application. If you will once use a load balancer, the balancer will not have to worry about which request has be delivered to which server. Any server can be used as the servers can **all** access the session data which is stored on a separate db host or cluster.